# Upgrades to Drupal in production

Tags: php, drupal, deployment

Does anyone have a good Drupal upgrade strategy for an install that is in production?  No one talks about this in books and it's hard to find a definitive answer in forums and email lists.

Ex:

1. Lock down prod, don't allow
   updates to data
   copy prod
2. copy prod database to dev
3. turn off all modules in dev
4. upgrade core Drupal in dev (update db if necessary)
5. upgrade modules in dev (update db if
   necessary)
6. turn on modules
7. test
8. migrate code and db to prod
9. turn site back on

Comment: Are you talking about a major upgrade, fx from 5 to 6

Comment: Hmmm good question.  I'm trying to figure out the best overall strategy.  Will a major upgrade require slightly different steps?

Comment: Absolutely.  Mr. French's answer only applies for a vanilla minor->minor upgrade, where there are no more add'l changes made in dev that need to be moved to prod.

Comment: Could the more major upgrade be included in step 2 in Mr. French's answer?

Comment: Actually I think that merging with custom code in dev should not be part of the process.  What you really want to do is copy prod code to an environment and upgrade that copy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your strategy sounds good, but it would require a site to be in “read only” mode for quite a while. This is not always feasible. Also I am not quite sure why you would turn on and off all of the modules?

May I propose a slightly different approach

1. copy prod database to dev
2. replicate prod code in dev
3. upgrade core Drupal in dev
4. run update.php
5. test
6. For each module
7. .   Upgrade modules in dev
8. .   Run update.php
9. .   Test
10. Put into maintenance mode
11. Backup database
12. Migrate code to production
13. Run update.php
14. Put back online test

This way there is a lot more testing but less downtime, also you will be able to work out which module breaks things if there is an error. It also dosn't rely on you uploading the DB from dev to live.

Comment: Done, also added "Backup database"

Comment: I think we should also put 'run update.php' in the dev environment...step 2.5

Comment: Good idea, I have changed, and also made this post wiki.

Comment: With your list, you basically say that at some point you can upgrade all your content by just running update.php. However, there is probably a point 13.5 where you need to change settings in the backend. As far as I have seen there is no way to do such setting changes beforehand, because settings and content are mixed in a single DB.

Answer (score 3):

Don't think there's any need to turn off modules before running update.php anymore (except maybe between major versions). And I definitely wouldn't run update.php once per module - that doesn't make sense with the way update hooks work.

If you're at all comfortable with the command-line (and running on a Linux server) then definitely have a look at [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush). It can simplify the process and allow parts of it to be scripted.

In addition, if you're looking for a formal update process to move stuff from your dev server to production for a large site, you should also be getting up to speed on the hooks that run during install and update.

Comment: Agreed - I've upgraded a number of Drupal sites on a regular basis without turning the modules off nor running update.php for each individual one.